# Why won't this code display on a wordpress page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, function

This code displays as plain text on any pages I put it on. It is supposed to display two text boxes and two buttons

```html
<div onmouseover="change_background(this, '#FCF6CF')" onmouseout="change_background(this,'#E8E8E8')" id="client_portal_content">
  Client Login
  <INPUT id=logintext size="15" onblur="if (this.value == '')
    this.value='Your client ID'" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Your client
    ID"></INPUT>
  <INPUT id=loginbutton onclick="if
    (document.getElementById('logintext').value != 'Your client ID')
    window.open('http://1010.cmmcloud.com/progress/progress.php?id=p-'+document.getElementById('logintext').value)" type=button value=Login></INPUT>

  <br><br> Affiliate Login
  <INPUT id=logintextaff size="15" onblur="if
    (this.value == '') this.value='Your affiliate ID'" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Your affiliate ID"></INPUT>
  <INPUT id=loginbuttonaff onclick="if
    (document.getElementById('logintextaff').value != 'Your affiliate ID')
    window.open('http://1010.cmmcloud.com/affportal/portal.php?id=a-'+document.getElementById('logintextaff').value)" type=button value=Login></INPUT>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in your code, which doesn't explain why it appears as plain text, but would explain why it won't run in any case. Instead of using a function 'onblur' to fill the text and then check if it's filled on submit, use **placeholder** text, and then check if the input is empty.

See below example:

```js
function check() {
  var x = document.getElementById("#myid");

  if (x == null|| x=="") {
    alert("Fill in your id!");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="myid" type="text" placeholder="Client ID" />

<button onclick="check();">Click me</button>
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:
In your  tag (which doesn't need to be capitalised, by-the-by), you have

```
 onclick="if
(document.getElementById('logintext').value != 'Your client ID'
```

Replace with

```
onclick="if
(document.getElementById('logintext').value != null  )


<input id="logintext" size="15" placeholder ="Your Client ID"
value=" "></input>
```

Comment: thank you rachel, but where would I put the function check() code? functions.php ??

Comment: in your case, you are writing functions in your input on click (not recommended practice, but I know wordpress is limited).. you can replace the function that you have on-click to check if the getElementById"loginText".value is null. The main thing is that you DON'T use on blur to set the text, use PLACEHOLDER text instead

Comment: @webdeveloper111132 see edited answer for example. You could also check for empty string by adding an ``&& (yourid.value) != " "

Comment: I'll try that. Also, when I add the functions to functions.php it states this: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR)

Comment: @webdeveloper111132 get RID of the onblur function and set the value to an empty string. My function is just an example for the snippet. You don't need to declare a variable

Comment: @webdeveloper111132 your id for your input should be in quotes.  e.g. <input id ="logintext" placeholder="Your Client Id" value ="">

Comment: thank you. So I don't need to add the function to functions.php then?

Comment: @webdeveloper111132 in short, no. Like I said earlier, you can replace your existing functions

Comment: @webdeveloper111132 you got it to work then? Always like a successful ending :)

Comment: thank you. I'll try replacing those and see if it works. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @webdeveloper111132 no problem. tips always come in useful ;) You'll be passing them on too :)